# Transferring ratings and playlists from Rhythmbox to Clementine

Tags: rhythmbox, clementine, playlists

After the latest update, Rhythmbox (which was my main mp3 player on my Ubuntu Latest distro) stopped functioning: it dies just after startup. So, I turned to Clementine which I like a lot. However in Rhythmbox I had my playlists and ratings. Song ratings are very important to me because many of my auto-playlists are depending on them.

Is there anyway I can get my playlists and ratings from Rhythmbox and add them to Clementine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To export a playlist select Music from the top menu and then Playlist, under which you have "save to file"

To export your ratings, create a smart playlist for each rating and then export those playlists too.

Comment: OP says that Rhythmbox crashes as soon as it starts up. So, your answer wouldn't help him.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary: fail, but probably for another reason

Hello,

Contrary to xpanta, my rhythmbox still works. So I used it to export playlists.

Then I launched Clementine to use that playlists to import ratings.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clementine-player/yGCZAsZe704 explains how to show "rating" and "score" column.

But both columns appear always empty. Double-clicking on a cell in the "Score" column (and only that one) allows to edit one value, but after pressing entry cell becomes blank again. Also, any batch rating/score function.

Is there something wrong with my clementine installation ? It's plain default install from Ubuntu 13.10.

Perhaps it's because the content of my Music folder is only symbolic links to actual locations, as other users do, see :

- [Issue 2299 - clementine-player - When adding music files to the library, symbolic links are being resolved, - A cross-platform music player based on Amarok 1.4 - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=2299)
- [Issue 1853 - clementine-player - clementine's library scanner doesn't follow symlinks pointing to relative paths - A cross-platform music player based on Amarok 1.4 - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=1853)
- [Issue 1870 - clementine-player - Library does not follow symbolic links in subdirectories - A cross-platform music player based on Amarok 1.4 - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=1870)

Those operations worked to import into gmusicbrowser, see details in [Transferring music ratings from rhythmbox to gmusicbrowser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370494/transferring-music-ratings-from-rhythmbox-to-gmusicbrowser)

I now use gmusicbrowser.