# Transferring music ratings from rhythmbox to gmusicbrowser

Tags: rhythmbox, music, gmusicbrowser

### Context

Used rhythmbox on older Ubuntu. Switched to Xubuntu 13.10. Default player is gmusicbrowser. Rhythmbox still available.

I have previously, on rhythmbox, patiently rated much of my music collection, which allows to let it play automatically enjoyable yet varied songs. As expected I'd like to transfer ratings to gmusicbrowser.

### Searching before asking

Rhythmbox stores ratings in XML format `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`.

Seeing how the content of `~/.config/gmusicbrowser/gmbrc` evolves with time shows that it contains all the data (music collection, metadata, ratings). It looks tab-separated.

Has anyone made a script to transfer ratings from the former to the latter ? I could not find any.

Notice that [Transferring ratings and playlists from Rhythmbox to Clementine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256406/transferring-ratings-and-playlists-from-rhythmbox-to-clementine) suggests exporting filtered playlists per rating and importing them to the new playser (Clementine in that case). This looks smart but makes assumptions about sending and receiving programs capabilities and tidyness.

#### Specific case

The solution mentioned above might work with gmusicbrowser. I'm just worried because my rhythmbox database is kind of "dirty". It has several occurrences of many songs (because is accessed them through different paths in its history and even lots of non-music files mentioned, making a 100MB rhythmdb.xml file, while the amount of actual music files mentioned in it is much much smaller than that...).

A script that walks gmusicbrowser database and writes a modified copy with cherry-picked ratings from rhythmbox database sounds better.

### Questions

- Has anyone done something similar ?
- Any other hint ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done for gmusicbrowser.

Here's how I did it finally!

- first clean up rhythmbox database using custom written XSLT style sheets. I can provide additional information on request (off-topic in this question).
- export playlists from rhythmbox (it happened to be pls format, others would have probably worked, too). I had playlists for "rating >=3 stars", same for 4 and 5.
- launch gmusicbrowser
- have it import all existing music, show it
- click on one line in the grid showing titles, press Ctrl-A select all
- right-click and choose "Edit rating" then choose a default rating (I set it to "no star")
- import "rating >=3 stars" in gmusicbrowser
- click on one line in the grid showing titles, press Ctrl-A select all
- right-click and choose "Edit rating" then choose 3 stars rating
- do the same for the playlists "rating >=4 stars" and 5.

Then I recreated the filters and sort orders.

This uses the capability of gmusicbrowser to allow batch edit rating, something rhythmbox cannot do.

I could not do that in Clementine. See [Transferring ratings and playlists from Rhythmbox to Clementine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256406/transferring-ratings-and-playlists-from-rhythmbox-to-clementine) for details, but probably for another reason.